# MatLab - Obtain histogram by column of matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, histogram

Simply put I have an N x M matrix and I would like to obtain a 256 bin histogram for each column of the matrix. I know how to do this with a for loop, but I need to do it in matrix notation to  save valuable computation time.

Also, I would like to use imhist rather than hist.

For loop method:

data = randint(100,100,10);

for n = 1:100

```
k(:,n) = imhist(data(n,:));
```

end

Answer (score 0):

`hist` operates on the column of the input matrix by default. So

```
>> k = hist( data, 0:255 );
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: @HughNolan look at the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) on the use case `hist(data,xcenters)`: second argument can be a vector.

Comment: I like that idea and it's essentially what I'm looking for, but the output in that case isn't the same as imhist...